# Как удалить выбранные элементы из массива?

Tags: php

У меня есть массив и из этого массива выбирается рандомное количество элементов. А выбранные элементы мы добавляем в пустой массив.  И мне надо удалит эти выбранные элементы. Я вытащил рандомное количество студентов, но не могу удалить  выбранные элементы.

```
<?php
    $used_arrays=  array();
    $input = array("Student 1", "Student 2", "Student 3", "Student 4", "Student 5", "Student 6", "Student 7", "Student 8", "Student 9", "Student 10");
    $count=count($input);
    $count3=mt_rand(1,($count-3));
    $rand_keys = array_rand($input, $count-3);
for ($i=0; $i <$count3 ; $i++) { 
        echo $random=$input[$rand_keys[$i]]."<br>";
        $used_arrays[]=$random;
}
?>
```

Comment: Я сам все сделал? Жаль что вопрос не удаляется.

Comment: почему не удаляется?

Comment: @Gaziza лучше напишите своё решение в качестве ответа, если сделали. Вдруг кому-нибудь в дальнейшем пригодится.